# How to mock an axios configuration module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, jestjs

I have a module which configures axios:

```
// config/axiosConfig.js
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1'
});

export default instance;
```

And a module that uses this to make api calls:

```
// store/actions.ts

import axiosInstance from 'config/axiosConfig';

export const fetchUsers = () => (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) => {
    dispatch(loading(true));
    return axiosInstance.get('/users')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch(loading(false));
            dispatch(fetched(res.data));
        })
        .catch(err => dispatch(error(true)));
}

...
```

I want to mock the axios config file to test my api file. I've tried many many ways but nothing works. I thought it would be as simple as

```
// store/actions.test.ts
import axiosInstance from 'config/axiosConfig';

jest.mock('config/axiosConfig');
axiosConfig.get.mockResolvedValue({users: mockUserList});

...
```

But I guess that's not how it works.

---

Edit: The approach in my question works when I put `axiosConfig.get.mockResolvedValue({users: mockUserList});` inside of the test, not right under the mock call.

Comment: Looks like you’ve done the right thing but I need to see your full test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out (Put this at the top of the file or at the top inside `beforeAll` or `beforeEach` depending on what you prefer):

```js
jest.mock('config/axiosConfig', () => ({
  async get(urlPath) {
    return {
      users: mockUserList,
    };
  },
}));
```

This is a simple mock using a factory function. To use a mock everywhere, `jest` provides a better way to avoid repeating yourself. You create a `__mocks__` directory and inside that, you can create your module and then override many of the builtins. Then, you can get away with just the following code.

```js
// file.test.ts

jest.mock('fs')

// Rest of your testing code below
```

Take a look at the [official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) to learn more about this.

If this doesn't work, then the module resolution setup in `jest.config.js` and `tsconfig.js` might be different.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Mind explaining why? Also, if I want the get method to return different things in different tests would that work with this setup? i.e. overriding the mocking of the get function in each test.

Comment: Yes. You just have to repeat these steps in each of your test files and set whatever you want to return in the get method (to avoid duplication, you can extract this out in a separate module and do some fun stuff with it). This is a simple mock where we provide a factory. Your approach requires a bit of setup like setting up `__mocks__` directory, etc. I have also updated the answer with the reason. Check it out.